# Floating and clearing five section tags

Tags: html, css-float, clearfix

I have five section tags that I would like to float so that they are inline with each other. I have used the float / clearfix technique in the past and it has worked. I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.

```
CSS:


    #content{ padding:30px 0 0 15px; width: 959px; }

    .clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

    .clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

     html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

    *html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}

#1, #2, #3, #4, #5 {padding-right:15px; float: left;}



HTML:
    <div id="content">      
      <section id="1">
        <img src="1.png" />
      </section>

      <section id="2">
        <img src="2.png" />
      </section>

      <section id="3">
        <img src="3.png" />
      </section>

      <section id="4">
        <img src="4.png" />
      </section>

      <section id="5">
        <img src="5.png" />
      </section>

     </div><!-- end content-->

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: I agree with @Asad, why isn't inline-block enough? Isn't it what you want to achieve : http://jsfiddle.net/2SMsU/

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you make your sections inline-block/floated and not clearfix?

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute *must* begin with a letter (a-z) - since your ids are just numbers, they are invalid and therefore never match.

Change your ids from `1`, `2`, `...` to `section1`, `section2`, `...`